# Failed to create a query for method. Creating a custom query in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am new to springboot, and I am trying to write a login method which will login user based on emailid and password or phone number and password.
In my service I have written something like this

```
public interface AuthService extends CrudRepository<AuthenticationModel, String> {
    Iterable<AuthenticationModel> findUserByEmailId(String emailId, String password);
    Iterable<AuthenticationModel> findUserByPhoneNumber(Long phoneNumber, String password);
}
```

I know methods like `findUserByEmailId` and `findUserByPhoneNumber` are not written in `CrudRepository` interface. That's why I am getting this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Iterable com.xyz.services.authenticate.AuthService.findUserByPhoneNumber(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)! No property phoneNumber found for type AuthenticationModel!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96)
```

What my concern is how can I implement my custom query in springboot ? I am aware of JPQL and native SQL implementations. But Is this recommended way of doing this ?
Say In future I am supposed to implement the search functionality, now search mechanism is itself a huge implementation. Can I implement the JPQL or native SQL implementation in search mechanism ? Or Is there another way which springboot provides which I am not aware of ?

I know there are lot of questions in one post. But I am confused when I tried to drill down to the actual answer on internet.

**EDIT:**
AuthenticationModel.class

```
public class AuthenticationModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "user_uuid", unique = true)
    private UUID userUuid;
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Email
    @Column(name = "user_email_id", unique = true)
    private String userEmailId;
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Positive
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "user_phone_number", unique = true)
    private Long userPhoneNumber;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String userPassword;
}
```

Comment: you can use @query notation to over your method and write complex queries for instance @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = 1")
Collection<User> findAllActiveUsers();   because writing long method name might not help you and is not recomended

Comment: Can you show us `AuthenticationModel` ?

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks, that's a entity model having uuid, email, phone, and password

Comment: Please add the model in post.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks, added. Can you tell me how that's going to help to answer my question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring data JPA derived query from the method name. You should use **exact field name** and parameter also for JPA method naming query. Here use `UserEmailId`, `UserPhoneNumber` and `UserPassword` in method name

```
List<AuthenticationModel> findByUserEmailIdAndUserPassword(String emailId, String password);
List<AuthenticationModel> findByUserPhoneNumberAndUserPassword(Long phoneNumber, String password);
```

Here you can read details about JPA method naming query  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Comment: oh!, it compiled without any issue ? I want to understand this, what happened ? Does the springboot form a query depending on the method name we give ? I am just running to see if this is working fine

Comment: The JPA module supports defining a query manually as a String or having it being derived from the method name. So from method name it derived the query automatically I added a doc about this in answer

Comment: I won't say thanks, I will upvote and accept your answer + Thanks :)